# Is ASP.NET MVC 3 ready for business applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to decide about a new big business application we will develop in the coming years, the question is if we should start using MVC 3 or web forms.

This was discussed already here in SO but I have seen the question: [ASP.NET MVC ready for business applications (integrating 3rd party controls/components)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221120/asp-net-mvc-ready-for-business-applications-integrating-3rd-party-controls-compo) was asked in 2008 and now many things could have changed.

My main concern is having heard MVC is good for rendering content like grids or lists and not so good for data input and user interaction.

Our application will have a lot of controls in which users are entering data and working with lists and text boxes, check boxes and so on.

is everything absolutely possible also in MVC or the classic Webforms and view state model would be more appropriate?

thanks.

Comment: After a few months... did you decide to use ASP.NET MVC 3? Can you already tell your opinions on the choice you've made? Thanks.

Comment: We are ramping up to start development in january. the recent release of devxpress 2011.2 library has given us confidence on the controls side as they finally added PivotGrid in MVC. about the technology and maturity of MVC considering the features planned for MVC 4 we are also confident we are going the right way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used every single version of WebForms since 1.0 beta and MVC 1, 2 and 3 and believe that MVC is definitely ready for production use.

You must take into consideration that the development approach of the 2 is quite different:

MVC requires that you learn more low level details of the basic web technologies: HTML, CSS, JS, HTTP,  (which I believe you should anyway if they are not in your skill set yet).

WebForms tries to abstract most of it and can be considered more productive for throwing together some simple pages. But it is a leaky abstraction and the lack of control may frustrate you as you grow more proficient - easier in the beginning if you are new to web development; harder to bend as you gain experience. 
The productivity gains start to disappear when the pages become more complex. The abstraction is more likely to cause performance problems and undermines the ability to automate testing of your pages (both unit and UI level testing with Selenium or equivalent tools).

Example 1: in MVC you most likely will need to understand how form fields are processed to compose a POST over HTTP with application/form-url-encoded, otherwise you may struggle with model binding. In WebForms you can build big applications without ever worrying with that.

Example 2: In MVC you need to manage most of your page state across requests. In WebForms it's easy have the framework do it for you.

MVC applications tend to rely more on client side javascript components for having reusable widgets, binding JSON data for example. WebForms encourages the use of server side controls since they integrate nicely into the framework state management facilities.

Unlike other people I don't believe in saying that MVC is strictly more productive than WebForms. Don't underestimate the WebForms ability to deliver data driven business applications quickly. Having managed a lot of people using both, my opinion is that MVC requires more skilled programmers to become more productive. But if that is your case you will likely find that MVC is a more enjoyable and powerful platform in those skilled hands.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that WebForms CAN be productive while MVC can do more but is more difficult. I love MVC but I also like WebForms and I can't understand people saying "MVC is light years ahead of WebForms". True, F1 bolid is light years ahead of my family car but it does not matter if I only want to drive to a nearby mall with my family.

Answer (score 25):

> Is ASP.NET MVC 3 ready for business applications
>
> is everything absolutely possible also in MVC

In my humble opinion; Absolutely 100% yes. In fact, I submit that the MVC framework is lightyears ahead of WebForms in both functionality and productivity.

Comment: +1 on ASP.NET MVC. When I have to return to ASP.NET WebForms from time to time, I'm physically suffering.

Comment: @Valentin - If I ever have to go back to WebFroms I think I might be physically _sick_.

Comment: thanks for your answer, are you doing a lot of data input operations and for example drag & drop between controls and server side processing in your applications? Do you find the third party controls/extensions for MVC mature and sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @Davide - I do alot of user interaction (form filling) as well as display. There is a HUGE amount of serverside processing in my app. I do not use any 3rd party controls. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Agreed. We have built a new product on MVC 3 (for retail) recently and in the last couple of years I have custom developed 4 critical enterprise business systems (in the logistics and e-government sectors) running in ASP.NET MVC 1 & 2. After spending 8 years in web forms, I hope to never look back. But it is a quite different from WebForms and be prepared for the learning curve.

Comment: +1.  I am new to it, but am writing a brand new application with it, am 80% in, and have yet to run into any major MVC3 limitations.  +1 to Telerik's MVC controls as well. They are pretty nice.

Comment: @MiguelVitorino Can you describe what is the different in the Learning curve between MVC and WebForms?

Comment: @EmadMokhtar - It depends, if you're from a WinForms or desktop dev background, WebForms will probably be easier to learn. If you're from a WebDev (PHP, ASP Classic) background, MVC will probably be easier. Its all relative to your current skills. However, saying that i'd still always suggest someone with no experience learn MVC because, as I stated in my post, MVC is so much better and more intuative than WinForms.

Comment: @EmadMokhtar My reply was getting too big for a comment so I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor is definitely ready for business applications.   I am building a large, enterprise-class web application in MVC 3 Razor C# and the more complexity I throw at MVC and the Entity Framewor, the better they handle it.  Let me give you a code example.  Lets say we want to create a dynamic table that mixes HTML with Razor C# code and data.  This is no small task using web forms and ASP.NET Web controls

```
<table>          
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Shipper</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (eStore.Models.Product p in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Hidden("Date", p.Date.ToString())
                @Html.Hidden("productId", p.ProductId)
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="@p.Name"/></td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Price", p.Price)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Quantity", p.Quantity)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Shipper", p.Shipper)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I have created a dynamic table containing a list of products with a button that can access more information on each product in the list by productId. This required a minimal amount of code and effort.   The code is clear, understandable and easy to edit.  Now imagine what would be required with conventional web forms and web controls to perform the same task.

There is a learning curve with MVC 3 but it is in my opinion well worth it.

Comment: +1 I don't know how much use this was to the poster but not being an MVCer I found your code example very interesting and a great example of the power of MVC and what it can do. I'm still not sure it fits into my idea of what the MVC design pattern does though...