# Choosing right framework for ASP.NET and C# development

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

We are planning to start a project on C# and ASP.net, So far we are using VS2008. Now the ASP.NET MVC3 is released. Is it good to start the new projects on ASP.NET MVC3 in VS2010.

Also there are other templates options are there in MVC3, which one is right to use. Are they stable enough to use it or we should continue the normal development in VS2008.

Comment: Your project should be functional driven, not technology.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4 and MVC3 are stable and used in production with no issue.

see my previous question as well: [Is ASP.NET MVC 3 ready for business applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124598/is-asp-net-mvc-3-ready-for-business-applications)

just mind the fact that if you go for the Razor view engine you have no design time rendering inside Visual Studio and you should use the browser while with classic aspx views you probably can preview the page layout inside Visual Studio. I still go for razor anywayn and we use the browser(s) for the preview

Comment: I second that. Perfect answer.

Comment: So what if there is no design time rendering? Just run the project in a browser.  Design / mock your layouts in html and css, then use them.

Comment: yes exactly. it's a matter of preferences, I have colleagues who feel lost when cannot see the page in Visual Studio at design time...

Comment: run the project in firefox or chrome, then tweak the css live by using Inspect Element (FireBug).  I NEVER use the design view in VS.  It was always crap anyway, especially for pages that are built from data.

Comment: In regards to previewing, this feature is promised to be available in MVC 4.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with vs2010 and MVC 3, if only for the fact that you can use Razor.  For MVC, .aspx files make writing and reading the display logic a pain.

Everything else is stable, tried and tested.

If you think about it, we are in the tail end of 2011.  We are almost in 2012.  VS 2010 came out in, well, 2010.

Also, Microsoft only ever gets a technology right in version 3.  As in MVC 3.

There are as yet no signs that they will screw it up in version 4...

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that `ASP.NET MVC` and `ASP.NET Web Forms` are completely different. Both have their place in web application development but if you are not familiar with developing with the MVC pattern (for example) and you don't have the time to learn, you should stick to what you feel comfortable with. I think you should try to make time to learn, if you haven't already done so.

In my personal opinion, MVC3 is the best framework. It's compliance with AJAX (particularly JQuery AJAX) and the Razor view engine make it very easy to develop feature rich applications very quickly.

VS2010 is enormously better than VS2008 imho. In terms of stability, I have built several application with MVC3 and Razor and to be honest, I think it is as, if not more, stable than MVC2.