# MVC or Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I a general question. When i want to develop some new web project (not simple page-something bigger and quite complex) what technology should i choose- MVC or Web Forms?

I've tried to find it myself but there are many different opinions about that topic. Is there any general rule or methodology which can help me decide?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124598/is-asp-net-mvc-3-ready-for-business-applications we are many to believe MVC is ready for complex/business applications. :)

Comment: General rule: **use what you know best**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no general rule. It's only a matter of preference. Someone likes MVC, someone likes webforms. Microsoft will support both equally.

Don't pick MVC vs Webforms based on the experience of someone else who says "THIS IS BETTER", because he's just plain wrong, but based on your instinct or how to describe it the best. You need to feel comfortable with the technology you're using, not struggle with it.

Comment: I agree, the article on CodeProject recently is a prime example of this.

Answer (score 4):

Basically both have their pons and cons for an overview of how you can decide see this blog

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/01/16/deciding-when-to-use-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

See these questions as well that already ask what you are looking for

[When to use ASP.NET MVC vs. ASP.NET Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144153/when-to-use-asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-web-forms)

[Traditional ASP .NET Web Forms vs MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712/traditional-asp-net-web-forms-vs-mvc)