# Stored Procedure value to asp.net page under text box

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

> I have a store procedure which show single row value like
>   (x.CLTotalAc, x.CLTotalAmt,x.CLAc, x.CLAmt,x.CL,
>   y.GB_CLTotalAc,y.GB_CLTotalAmt, y.GB_CLAc, y.GB_CLAmt, y.GB_CL).
>
> I want these value to my asp.net C# page under text box (txtCLTotalAmt,
>   txtCL, txtGB_CLTotalAmt, txtGB_CL)
>
> Store Procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Cr_CL_Report] 

@ProductName text,
@BranchName text

as
begin
Select x.CLTotalAc,x.CLTotalAmt,x.CLAc, x.CLAmt,x.CL,
y.GB_CLTotalAc,y.GB_CLTotalAmt, y.GB_CLAc, y.GB_CLAmt, y.GB_CL
from 
(
SELECT COUNT(dbo.DDBranchName.BCode) AS BrCode, 
    dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName AS ProductName, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAc) AS CLTotalAc, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAmt) AS CLTotalAmt, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAc) AS CLAc, SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAmt) AS CLAmt, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAmt)/SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAmt) * 100 AS CL
FROM dbo.DDBranchName INNER JOIN
dbo.TblTotalCL ON dbo.DDBranchName.BCode = dbo.TblTotalCL.CLbrCode
    WHERE (dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAsOnDate IN
        (SELECT MAX(CLAsOnDate) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.TblTotalCL AS TblTotalCL_1)) 
    AND (dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName LIKE @ProductName) 
    AND (dbo.DDBranchName.BCode LIKE @BranchName)
GROUP BY dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName
) x
inner join
(
SELECT  COUNT(dbo.DDBranchName.BCode) AS GB_BrCode, 
    dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName AS GB_ProductName, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAc) AS GB_CLTotalAc, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAmt) AS GB_CLTotalAmt, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAc) AS GB_CLAc, 
    SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAmt) AS GB_CLAmt, 
    (SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAmt) / SUM(dbo.TblTotalCL.CLTotalAmt))*100 AS GB_CL
FROM dbo.DDBranchName INNER JOIN
dbo.TblTotalCL ON dbo.DDBranchName.BCode = dbo.TblTotalCL.CLbrCode
    WHERE (dbo.TblTotalCL.CLAsOnDate IN
        (SELECT MAX(CLAsOnDate) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.TblTotalCL AS TblTotalCL_1)) 
AND (dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName LIKE @ProductName) 



GROUP BY dbo.TblTotalCL.CLProductName 
)  y on
x.ProductName = y.GB_ProductName

end
```

> Blockquote

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Getting return value from stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)

In the link you can see how to get the values form a stored procedure. Then assign the value to the text box

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading up on Ado.net. Use for instance the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),under adonet data provider examples/sqlclient. When you have this working you have retrieved the data from the database. (imho avoid table adapters, entity framework and linqtosql if you want to grok it. instead go with manually writing for [SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program). or [dapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET) to ease some of the burden.)

Now you have to get it to the web page. First decide on [Webforms or Aspnetmvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380986/mvc-or-web-forms). Then googlewithbing what the syntax is like.

Wash.
Rinse.
Repeat.

HTH